# Error using Yield in VB.NET - Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses

Tags: .net, vb.net, ienumerable, yield

I am trying to create a recursive function to return all descendants of a control in an `IEnmerable(Of Control)`. I created a function returning `IEnumerable(Of Control)` and used `Yield`:

```
Public Function GetControls(C As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    For Each Child As Control In C.Controls
        Yield Child
        For Each GrandChild In GetControls(Child)
            Yield GrandChild
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

But I have a compile time error:

> Error BC30800, Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses.

I tried to use it like function `Yield(Child)` or `Yield Return Child` or `Return Yield Child` but still having the error.

I couldn't find anything related to the problem by searching the error message in google or bing. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Which version of VB/.NET/Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @StevenDoggart I'm using Visual Studio 2017 .NET 4.6.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using [`Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/yield-statement) statement in VB.NET, the function should be defined as `Iterator`:

```
Public Iterator Function GetControls(C As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    For Each Child As Control In C.Controls
        Yield Child
        For Each GrandChild In GetControls(Child)
            Yield GrandChild
        Next
    Next
End Function
```